# How to add inbuilt tool of Powerpoint in Custom UI Editor Customized Tab

Tags: vba, powerpoint

As I was creating customized tab which will help me all the tool I use in single tab with the help of **"Custom UI"** in that I can add which i have scripted, but not getting how to add the inbuilt tool of powerpoint for example "Font Color Picker" i want to add what should I do.

Below are the script

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="GEPper">
                <group id="TextTools" label="Text Tools">
                    <button id="FontSize" label=" " image="a4" size="normal" onAction="FontSize" screentip="Font Size 10" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="FontSize12" label=" " image="a3" size="normal" onAction="FontSize12" screentip="Font Size 12" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="FontSize14" label=" " image="a2" size="normal" onAction="FontSize14" screentip="Font Size 14" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="FontSize16" label=" " image="a1" size="normal" onAction="FontSize16" screentip="Font Size 16" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="FontColorBlack" label=" " image="black" size="normal" onAction="FontColorBlack" screentip="Font Color Black" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="FontColorWhite" label=" " image="white" size="normal" onAction="FontColorWhite" screentip="Font Color White" supertip=" "/>
                    <button id="Bullet" label=" " image="bullet" size="normal" onAction="Bullet" screentip="Bullet Color Black" supertip=" "/>
                    <button idMso="FontColorPicker"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

It would be great help if anyone can help me out

Comment: I think you can find your question in example 2 of this site, but I'm not sure: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm

Comment: Have Tried this
```Sub FontColorPicker()
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FontcolorPicker"
End Sub
```
But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a ribbon mod, the XML for a built-in gallery looks like this:

```
<gallery
  idMso="FontColorPicker"
  showImage="true"
  showLabel="false"/>
```

To find other idMso identifiers, you need to reference a set of Excel spreadsheets published by Microsoft. Here's the link for the 2016 (also applies to 2019) files: [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

There is one workbook for PowerPoint. Search the first column.

Comment: You can often find the name of the control in the Customize Ribbon dialog box.  Locate the control you want to add, hover over it with the mouse and the last bit of the tooltip, (the part in parentheses) will give you the name you need to add to your RibbonX.